# JavaScript FormData not sending to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, form-data

I have made a simple drag and drop application that sends the file you have dropped (an image) to an PHP-file that checks the file and uploads everything. I send an object with variables to the PHP, and the PHP get's the object, **but not the file.** I have tried several Google searches and tweaks with my code, but I can't get it to upload the file for me.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var DropField = document.getElementById("prof_upload_field")
    resDiv = document.getElementById("prof_upl_res_field")
    formData = new FormData(),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Add class to dropblock when item is dragged over document
document.ondragover = function(){

    // Add "dragover" class to dropblock
    DropField.className = 'dragOver';
    DropField.innerHTML = 'Drop here!';
}

// When something is dropped
DropField.ondrop = function(e){

    console.log('Something has been dropped!');

    e.preventDefault();
    // Get file from drop
    var files = e.dataTransfer.files,
        // Object to fill
        object = {};

    // Fill object with values from file
    object = {
        fileName: files[0].name,
        fileSize: files[0].size,
        fileType: files[0].type,
    }

    if(files.length > 1){
        resDiv.innerHTML = 'You can only select 1 file!';
        throw('You can&#39;t upload more than 1 profile picture!');
    }

    var fileData = JSON.stringify(object);
    formData.append('file', files[0]);
    formData.append('filedata', fileData);

    xhr.open("POST", "ajax/upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(formData);

    xhr.onload = function(){
        resDiv.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }

    console.log(object);
}

// When something is dragged into the dropblock
DropField.ondragover = function(){
    console.log('Something is dragged in the dropblock!');

    // Return false to allow a file begin dropped
    return false;
}


// When the cursor has left the dropblock   
DropField.ondragleave = function(){
    console.log('Cursor left the dropblock!');

    // Return false to allow a file begin dropped
    return false;
}
```

When I do a print_r($_POST) it displays the object that I have send, but not the file. I have a JSFiddle right here:

http://jsfiddle.net/v0qpr7p1/

Comment: Uploaded files appear in `$_FILES` so do a `print_r` on that to see what you get.

Comment: Not stupid, you're just learning!